# Como editar as rotas criadas pelo comando make:auth?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, rotas, auth

Tenho um projeto no Laravel onde utilizei o comando `make:auth` para criar as *views*, rotas, *controllers* e etc, de um formulário de cadastro.

Preciso alterar o a *view* que é utilizada por padrão no *login* para uma `view` que criei a mão.

**Dúvida**:

- Tem como editar essa *view* ou rota?
- Se sim, onde?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neste caso em específico de mudar as *views* você vai querer seguir a recomendação do amigo @Wallace Maxters. Este é o caminho recomendável. ;)

Na eventual necessidade de personalizar as rotas, você pode simplesmente comentar a linha `Auth::routes()` do arquivo `routes/web.php` e declarar as rotas manualmente seguindo [o modelo de como elas foram declaradas](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php#L994) (estou usando o Laravel 5.4 como referência):

```
// Authentication Routes...
$this->get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
$this->post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
$this->post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

// Registration Routes...
$this->get('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
$this->post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');

// Password Reset Routes...
$this->get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.request');
$this->post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('password.email');
$this->get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset');
$this->post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset');
```

Para não precisar mudar nada no código você só precisa manter os nomes das rotas e manter a mesma URL nas rotas que repetem a URL, de modo que você pode por exemplo traduzir a URL `login` para `entrar` desde que você faça isso tanto na rota GET como na rota POST.

De modo geral você não precisa trocar os métodos que as rotas apontam uma vez que você pode sobrecarregar eles diretamente nas classes que eles dependem. ;)

Comment: É sempre interessante trazer a informação de como o framework trabalha internamente. +1

Comment: Particularmente, eu sempre excluo tudo de  autenticação do Laravel e faço na mão. Sempre preciso personalizar alguma coisa, kkkkkkk

Comment: Como faço p/ após me logar ou registrar algum usuário, retorne para uma view criada por mim e não a \home?

Answer (score 5):

Isso vai depender da versão do Laravel que você está usando.

## Laravel 5.2

Você precisa adicionar a propriedade `$loginView` na classe `AuthController`.

Assim:

```
protected $loginView = 'nome_da_minha_view';
```

No código fonte do `trait` chamado `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers`, há um método chamado `showLoginForm`, que está escrito assim:

```
/**
 * Show the application login form.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function showLoginForm()
{
    $view = property_exists($this, 'loginView')
                ? $this->loginView : 'auth.authenticate';

    if (view()->exists($view)) {
        return view($view);
    }

    return view('auth.login');
}
```

observe que, se existir a propriedade `loginView` na classe atual (nesse contexto seria `AuthController`), a view utilizada será a definida nessa propriedade, caso a `view`  também exista (conforme a verificação de `view()->exists()`.

## Laravel 5.3 e 5.4

Você precisa simplesmente sobrescrever o método chamado `showLoginForm` na classe de autenticação e retornar a `view` desejada.

```
  public function showLoginForm()
  {
        return view('minha_view_personalizada');
  }
```

Há ainda uma outra dica, que é de criar o método chamado `getLogin` retornando a `view`. Surtirá o mesmo efeito que o demonstrado acima com `showLoginForm`.

Comment: O meu Laravel está na versão 5.4... Por isso, onde encontro esse 'showLoginForm'?

Comment: Meu projeto n possui AuthController